# create-react-app + typescript does not use browserslist

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

create-react-app by default uses [browserslist](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features/#configuring-supported-browsers), but as I see it works only for `*.js` files (I'm not so sure), for `*.ts` no difference.

My env (generated by [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/)):

- webpack: ~4.29.6
- react: ~16.12.0
- typescript: ~3.7.2

Code of project consists of `*.ts` / `*.tsx` files only.

I've tried to add `Object.entries` polyfill by:

1. Changing `browserslist` in `package.json` by adding `IE 9`, `chrome >20`, etc... - **But to no avail** (dist was not changed)
2. Changing `compilerOptions.target` in `tsconfig.json` to `es5` - **But to no avail** (dist was not changed)
3. Adding to `compilerOptions.lib` in `tsconfig.json` new values: `es5`,`es6`,`es7`, etc... - **But to no avail** (dist was not changed)

Only adding `import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';` gives me `Object.entries` polyfill, but with ~600kb of other polyfills :(

Questions:

1. Is [browserslist](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features/#configuring-supported-browsers) in create-react-app project uses ONLY for `*.js` files?
2. Is there currently no way to use [browserslist](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features/#configuring-supported-browsers) for auto-adding polyfills for compiling TypeScript project?
3. Is [browserslist](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features/#configuring-supported-browsers) completely useless for TypeScript project?

Answer (score 2):

My main mistake:

> When editing the browserslist config, you may notice that your changes don't get picked up right away. This is due to an [issue in babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/690) not detecting the change in your package.json. A quick solution is to delete the node_modules/.cache folder and try again.

`rm -rf node_modules/.cache` before build given completely different result.

> Is browserslist in create-react-app project uses ONLY for *.js files?

Nope, this works with `*.ts` / `*.tsx` too.

> Is there currently no way to use browserslist for auto-adding polyfills for compiling TypeScript project?

Polyfills does't includes by default, need to use [react-app-polyfill](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-app-polyfill)

`react-app-polyfill` doc:

> You can also polyfill stable language features not available in your target browsers. If you're using this in Create React App, **it will automatically use the browserslist you've defined to only include polyfills** needed by your target browsers when importing the stable polyfill.